# MSSQL two inner joins to the same table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table listing a bunch of timesheets (TK.DETAIL).

In that table it references the employees ID, which I can successfully use to pull the first name and last name from the employee table (EMMain)

The TK.DETAIL table also shows me a Project ID and I can obtain the supervisor ID of that project by INNER joining the project table (PR).

What I am trying to do is JOIN the PR and EMMain tables to obtain the first name and last name of the supervisor.

My current query gives me the same first name and last name of the Employee ID.

What am I doing wrong.

```
   SELECT        tkDetail.Employee, tkDetail.WBS1, tkDetail.WBS2, tkDetail.LineItemApprovalStatus, tkDetail.LineItemApprover, PR.Supervisor, EMMain.LastName, EMMain.FirstName,EMMain.FirstName AS SupervisorFirst, EMMain.LastName AS supervisorlast
FROM            tkDetail INNER JOIN
                         PR ON tkDetail.WBS1 = PR.WBS1 INNER JOIN
                         EMMain ON tkDetail.Employee = EMMain.Employee INNER JOIN
                         EMMain AS EMPL ON PR.Supervisor = EMMain.Employee

WHERE (LineItemApprovalStatus is NULL)
```

Comment: Are you sure about " AND PR.Supervisor = EMMain.Employee" from the second join?
That mean EMMain.Employee = tkDetail.Employee = PR.Supervisor

Comment: that's what I'm not sure about. EMMain.Employee is the employee ID. tkDetail.Employee and PR.Supervisor are also employee ID's

Comment: Trying to get the Supervisor Firstname and Kastname using following. EMMain.FirstName AS SupervisorFirst, EMMain.LastName AS supervisorlas

Comment: Or try to join PR second on both conditions.

Comment: I have edited my answer,please check again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see if left join helps and take care that on third join you should use EMPL alias not the table name again

```
     SELECT tkDetail.Employee, tkDetail.WBS1, tkDetail.WBS2, 
     tkDetail.LineItemApprovalStatus, tkDetail.LineItemApprover, 
     PR.Supervisor, EMMain.LastName, EMMain.FirstName,SUP.FirstName AS 
      SupervisorFirst, SUP.LastName AS supervisorlast 
FROM tkDetail 
INNER JOIN PR ON tkDetail.WBS1 = PR.WBS1 
left JOIN EMMain ON tkDetail.Employee = EMMain.Employee 
left JOIN EMMain SUP ON PR.Supervisor = SUP.Employee WHERE (LineItemApprovalStatus is NULL)
```

Comment: Hi Radu, not stil no good. I've tried RIGHT, LEFT / LEFT, LEFT / LEFT, RGITH / RIGHT, RIGHT.

Comment: I think I found it :)
In the select field list I change to SUP.FirstNAme and SUP.LASTNAME and also on the last left join I have changed to SUP alias, please see my answer edited :)

Answer (score 0):

Without data is hard to say, but try do like this

```
SELECT *
FROM tkDetail 
INNER JOIN PR ON tkDetail.WBS1 = PR.WBS1 
INNER JOIN EMMain PR.Supervisor = EMMain.Employee
WHERE (LineItemApprovalStatus is NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will work like that:

```
    SELECT tkDetail.Employee, tkDetail.WBS1, tkDetail.WBS2, tkDetail.LineItemApprovalStatus, tkDetail.LineItemApprover, PR.Supervisor, EMMain.LastName, EMMain.FirstName,EMMain.FirstName AS SupervisorFirst, EMMain.LastName AS supervisorlast
    FROM tkDetail INNER JOIN
     EMMain ON tkDetail.Employee = EMMain.Employee INNER JOIN 
     PR ON tkDetail.WBS1 = PR.WBS1 AND EMMain.Employee = PR.Supervisor  
    WHERE (LineItemApprovalStatus is NULL)
```

Comment: sorry no go, it then changes the supervisorID to match the employee ID

Comment: Is the same condition from the first version of your question :)

Comment: Try to use left join on last two joins  :)   SELECT        tkDetail.Employee, tkDetail.WBS1, tkDetail.WBS2, tkDetail.LineItemApprovalStatus, tkDetail.LineItemApprover, PR.Supervisor, EMMain.LastName, EMMain.FirstName,EMMain.FirstName AS SupervisorFirst, EMMain.LastName AS supervisorlast
FROM            tkDetail INNER JOIN
                         PR ON tkDetail.WBS1 = PR.WBS1 left JOIN
                         EMMain ON tkDetail.Employee = EMMain.Employee 
left JOIN
                         EMMain AS EMPL ON PR.Supervisor = EMMain.Employee

WHERE (LineItemApprovalStatus is NULL)